# PHP PDO Select Query Results

Tags: php, pdo

This seems like it should be a very easy task, but I'm not sure it is.

I would like to use PDO to do a SELECT query, and then immediately after find out if there are any results (rows), and if so how many.

I'd like to fetch the result as an object not an array, as I like the $obj->col_name syntax, and it just feels a bit wrong to return an array just to find the above out.

```
$qryh = $conn->query("SELECT ...");
```

Then use `$qryh` to first find out if there are any rows, and if so how many.

Can this be done without falling back to using arrays..?

**UPDATE:**

I know about `rowCount()`, but I think it only works on UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE - my question relates to SELECT.

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm using SQL Server and MS Access, not MySQL, and rocount() does not work.

**SOLUTION FOUND**

The accepted answer lead to the solution. Here is what I found:

I was setting the `PDO::ATTR_CURSOR` option to `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL` when creating the PDO object (`new PDO(...`), which returned `-1` on a `rowCount()`. However if I set the cursor within `->prepare(...` using an array (`array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)`) it works and returns the row count.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628154(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628154%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

So, the example on the above link works, setting the cursor when you create the PDO object doesn't work. Also note that in the 'remarks' section on the above link, it mentions `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLLABLE` which doesn't for me (I get `Undefined class constant 'CURSOR_SCROLLABLE'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$query = "select * from ...";
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
$stmt->execute();
print $stmt->rowCount()
```

Should work

Comment: rowCount doesn't work on SELECT does it...? Only UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE..?!!

Comment: Only with MySQL I think

Comment: "However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications." Which means, if it works with his Database, he can rely on it.

Comment: Thanks gaijinjim, but it doesn't work, I'm using SQL Server and MS Access - not MySQL...

Comment: Check my Edited answer, it should work like this. Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628154(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks GaijinJim - Setting the cursor is the most promising lead I have, but using `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL` gives me `-1`, and using `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLLABLE` (from the MS link you gave) gives me `Undefined class constant 'CURSOR_SCROLLABLE'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT ...');
// number of rows:
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();

// get an array with objects:
$objects = $stmt->fetchAll();

// another way to count the results:
$rows = count($objects);
```

Comment: rowCount doesn't work on SELECT does it...? Only UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE..?!!

Comment: Why not? It count either the result rows, or the affected rows by the statements you mentioned. So it simplifies things here.

Comment: "returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE"

Comment: Yeah, the next sentence tells you what I just said.

Comment: Updated my answer to be on the save side with the result

Comment: Thanks colburton, but your update uses an array which like I said in my question, I don't want to use...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in my database class:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ...');
$stmt->execute();

$arrayOfObjects = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$numberOfRows = count($arrayOfObjects);
print $numberOfRows;
```

By passing `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` each object is an `stdClass` meaning you can use the `->` syntax.

I believe this is what you are looking for, and it just uses the PHP `count()` function instead of mySQL `rowCount()`.

If you want more context, here is the DB class I use in all of my projects: https://gist.github.com/pxlsqre/9f6471220ef187343f54

Comment: Thanks JasonSilberman, but that still returns an array not an object so I don't see how I can use the -> syntax. I tried it and got: `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, `PDO::rowCount` does not work properly with SELECT

One workaround is to Add the count to your query

```
$qryh = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as numRows FROM Table");
$result = $qryh->(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);;
$count = $result->numRows;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$qryh->fetchColumn()
```

Returns the number of rows selected through a SELECT query

Comment: fetchColumn return the first column, hence the name!